# How can I marshall between XLOPER and VARIANT?

Tags: c++, excel, marshalling, variant, safearray

I'm working on an Excel plugin (XLL), which communicates with COM objects.  So, I have to marshall between XLOPER and VARIANT.  I've got most of this working, but arrays are definitely a pain.  I need to support 1- and 2D arrays.

I imagine someone has already had to deal with this before.  What's the best way to simplify dealing with VARIANT, SAFEARRAY, and XLOPER (and XLOPER12)?

Comment: see this new post for an answer :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27473463/how-to-return-xloper-excel-variable-to-vba-directly-from-a-c-dll

Comment: Since Malik's link above is dead, here's an archive.org version http://web.archive.org/web/20150616142740/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27473463/how-to-return-xloper-excel-variable-to-vba-directly-from-a-c-dll

Comment: Thanks @AndyTerra , I don't know why I have deleted my post ... I just undeleted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to hand-roll my own marshalling code for this.  There were no freely available libs to handle this.  XLW is meant for wrapping your entire plugin - this was not an option for me.

In the end, it just took a lot of time, looking through the documentation for xloper and variant, and figuring out how to map them to each other.

For the curious:

arrays in xloper(12):

- .xltype is xltypeMulti
- .val.array is a pointer to an array of xlopers.

arrays in variant:

- .vt is VT_ARRAY | VT_VARIANT
- .parray is a SafeArray of variants

other tips with this marshalling:

- xltypeRef and xltypeSRef: use xlCoerce to look up actual cell values.
- integer values run the risk of overflow.  `boost::numeric_cast` helps with that.
- string marshalling is annoying.  xloper uses char, xloper12 uses wchar, variant uses bstr.
- Remember to free the buffers you allocate for your new xloper strings.  Use xlbitDLLFree and xlAutoFree(12) accordingly.
- Template programming is useful for the xloper/xloper12 issue.  Boost helps.  _bstr_t also helps.

Comment: Can I contact you offline reg. this? I have an UDF written in C++ that needs to return a 2-d variant array by stashing it into a XLOPER. I get nightmares just thinking about it.

Comment: @Dilip, post that as a question here on SO.  I (or others) can answer it.  I'd be happy to help you out; I just prefer to keep answers public, to help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I use XLL Plus (costs)
http://www.as-ltd.co.uk/xllplus/default.htm

There is also XLW (opensource)
http://xlw.sourceforge.net/

and probably others I am not aware of