# How to return XLOPER (Excel Variable) to VBA directly from a c++ dll?

Tags: c++, vba, vsto, xll

I have no idea how to handle XLOPER type variable in VBA. There are plenty of web pages explaining the relationship between Xloper variable , c++ DLL **and** XLL add-in, however i need to  write c++ function in a dll returning a xloper directly to VBA without XLL framework. (No need of User Defined Function since functions from the dll will be called by the VBA code - not by Excel users).

Indeed i'm coding a Excel VSTO and i need to call c++ code from it. I found that xloper variable are very useful for XLL so i would like to use this variable type in VBA/VB.Net directly. So is it possible?

- my guess it that the xloper can be handled using variant type but i don't know how.
  i found this post :[How can I marshall between XLOPER and VARIANT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514679/how-can-i-marshall-between-xloper-and-variant)  but there is no clear answer.

EDIT :

sorry if i wasn't clear , so for instance i made this c++ function receiving a Int from excel and returning the same value plus 5 as a xloper variale to excel.

```
  _declspec(dllexport) xloper  _stdcall returnInt( int iVal)
 {
 xloper pxlval_ret;
 int a ;
 a =5 + iVal;

 pxlval_ret->xltype = xltypeInt;
 pxlval_ret->val.w =  a ;

 return pxlval_ret;
}
```

but i don't know how do call it in vba, Is the return variable a VARIANT?

Comment: i have read the book Financial Applications using Excel Add-in Development in C / C++, 2nd Edition by Steve Dalton but there is no simple example so I m totally lost.

Comment: You can't XLOPER is called from functions in the spreadsheet and VBA cannot call them directly. So you have to have the wrappers answered in the other question

Comment: Ps : if someone know a library doing this job, please tell us,then i will put the question as answered.

Comment: Grebe this is a duplicate of the other question :( Basically XLOPER pass data from Excel functions to DLL - for VBA has a different call to DLL or use Visual Studio tools. (The examples in the book you mention probably show the best way to use them) NB I found it easier to write all the code in C rather than use VBA - but now I would look at VSTO

Answer (score 2):

finally I read attentively the book "Excel Add-in Development in C / C++, 2nd Edition by Steve Dalton". It answers the question and provides source code for it. If you want to perform this operation you need to create a xloper wrapper, the xloper_to_v function which is par of xloper.cpp of the aforementioned book do this job. Due to copyrights, I can't publish here the whole code but just some lines of codes; i think it can give some useful insight:

```
bool xloper_to_vt(const xloper *p_op, VARIANT &var, bool convert_array)
{
VariantInit(&var); // type is set to VT_EMPTY

switch(p_op->xltype)
{
case xltypeNum:
    var.vt = VT_R8;
    var.dblVal = p_op->val.num;
    break;

case xltypeInt:
    var.vt = VT_I2;
    var.iVal = p_op->val.w;
    break;

case xltypeBool:
   // see in the book

case xltypeStr:
    // see in the book

case xltypeErr:
    // see in the book

case xltypeMulti:
    if(convert_array)
    {
        VARIANT temp_vt;
        SAFEARRAYBOUND bound[2];
        long elt_index[2];

        // see in the book

        xloper *p_op_temp = p_op->val.array.lparray;

        for(WORD r = 0; r < p_op->val.array.rows; r++)
        {
            for(WORD c = 0; c < p_op->val.array.columns;)
            {
            // see in the book
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    // else, fall through to default option

default: // type not converted
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```